# Split-apply-combine in Rcpp, or does tapply have a Rcpp sugar-equivalent?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, syntactic-sugar

Note that I am just starting to touch `Rcpp` in order to speed up some function. I am otherwise familiar with `R`, but not so much with `C++` or programming (other than R) in general. So please take my apologies for unintelligent questions bound to come...

I am looking for a `Rcpp` way to apply a split-apply-combine routine to some data. Think of the base `R` function `tapply`. The rcpp-sugar vignette only mentiones `sugar` versions of `sapply` and `lapply`. However, split-apply-combine routines are so common that I suspect that there is something out there (`sugar` or not), but I did not find it. After all, this can be done using `base (tapply, aggregate), plyr, dplyr, data.table`, and probably some other ways in R. This makes me think there should be some convenience functions for `Rcpp` as well but I have missed them. I would appreciate any pointers.

Background: Profiling a particular (time-consuming) bootstrap procedure reveals that the repeated call to a function computing cluster robust standard errors is the bottleneck. For that reason I am looking for ways to speed up that function, and `Rcpp` is something that sounds promising. The core function of my bootstrap procedure is based on the [first function (`clx`) defined here by M. Arai](http://people.su.se/~ma/clmclx.R), even though using `data.table` instead of the `apply-tapply`-construction and using explicit matrix multiplication (i.e. avoiding using `sandwich`) already speeds up that function dramatically, but not enough. Since I need to call that function several thousand times, I have been wondering about a more efficient implementation, and `Rcpp` came to mind. I don't know how to do the split-apply-combine part of that function, though.

Comment: Rcpp has no tapply. What worker function are your trying to use. Do you really need this down C++ or can you just use dplyr or similar.

Comment: I have added some background, which may help. To your question: I have been thinking of calling `data.table` from within `Rcpp` for this task, but in some of Dirk Eddelbuettel's posts I read that this is not recommended, given that I need to call this function several thousand times. For that reason I was wondering about a "pure" `Rcpp` solution. Needless to say, I appreciate any comments about possible strategies.

Comment: I do not think we have anything already made for you, other than calling back which has overhead. You could try to expose the functionality of `data.table` to your code, but that is probably not trivial.  So you may have to code some functionality yourself, or live with the cost of calling back to `data.table`.

Comment: Based on the link you showed, and the clustered standard error problem setting, I would look into RcppArmadillo to (re-)implement the core of your bootstrap problem with Armadillo.

Comment: bootstrap based grouping is on our dplyr todo list. Not sure this will suit your needs. Otherwise, for that particular example, you are just looking for a glorified for loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks Romain and Dirk! Since split-apply-combine routines are so common in R, I expected some `sugar` for that, but at least now I know that I haven't just overlooked something. Glorified loop it will be! Thanks for your comments, and thanks in general! I really appreciate all the work you guys put in.